# How can I register generic interfaces with Func (servicestack fork)

Tags: dependency-injection, servicestack

```
container.Register <IRep<T>>(c => new Rep<T>())); /// Exception :)

container.RegisterAllTypesOf<IRep> (....)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Funq doesn't support this out of the box, see this comment from the owner - [How do I register a generic service](http://funq.codeplex.com/discussions/79357). Your best bet is to make use of your ability to provide your own container. I know that Autofac supports this - [Autofac Open Generics](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/OpenGenerics)